# How to prevent iphone from appearing calibrating compass in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

when I set my MKMapView's userTrackingMode to MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading, my app shows me compass calibration again and again. How to prevent it from this?
Here is my locationManager's initialization.

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 5;
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationType = LocationManagerTypeNone;
```

Comment: Since you want the heading use the compass and the compass needs to be calibrated you can't really prevent it

Answer (score 0):

CLLocationManagerDelegate has a method to disable the calibration display,

https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration:

but I'm not sure if MKMapView has a different one you can't change...

Comment: Yes I have this method and return NO. But it is never called.